# Compute 2D FFT in NumPy

Tags: numpy, fft

I load image in NumPy using `imageio` and it loads in the format `H x W x 3` where `H` and `W` are the spatial axes and `3` refers to RGB channels.

I wish to compute the images 2D FFT and use `np.fft.fft2(img)`. I look at the documentation of np.fft.fft2 and it uses `axes=(-2,-1)`. Does this mean that my FFT is being computed over the `W` and the `3` axes?

Will the correct way be `np.fft.fft2(img,axes=(0,1))`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the solution that you suggest, but another option may be to calculate the transform for every color, do your processing, and merge again after if needed.

Something like this:

```
image_red, image_green, image_blue = imageio[:,:,0], imageio[:,:,1], imageio[:,:,2]

fft_red = np.fft.fft(image_red)
```

etc...

You can plot the proposed solution and this method to check the difference, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure('onlyRed')
plt.imshow(np.abs(fft_red))
```

Comment: Yes this obvious solution is lengthy both from code and execution time perspective.

Comment: Mostly I am sure o/p of `np.fft.fft2(img,axes=(0,1))` should be same as decomposing and doing FFT individually. What do you suggest?

Comment: You can simply try what you suggest with a simple image and check the result. I think it should work as you said. I am not sure about your question though.
Another solution would be to have your images in a list and use the "map" function from multiprocessing to run multiple transforms in parallel. This would allow you to be faster if speed is the problem.